# Does .Net's WebClient class support ETag "out of the box"?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, webclient, etag

In the code sample below I am calling the same URL twice from a single WebClient object:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var url = "http://windows.microsoft.com/scripts/4.2/wol/modernizr.wol.js";
var result = client.DownloadString(url);
// Imagine some work done here:
Thread.Sleep(5000);
var result2 = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Can I trust the WebClient to respect the ETag returned from this URL, send it on the second request to the server and properly recognize the server's 304 status code?

I know I can add code to store the ETag from the first response and send it out with the second response (as a "If-None-Match" header). My question is - do I have to?

Bonus question: If you actually run the above code and sniff it (ex: w/ Fiddler2), you will see that WebClient only makes the first request and never makes the second request. Why?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Cache/RequestCache.cs

Comment: @SLaks Umm. Can you please elaborate on how this link answers my question? Tx.